# How can we integrate sonarqube in android studio (gradle version is above 3.)?

Tags: android, sonarqube

How can we integrate sonarqube in android studio (gradle version is above 3.). I have already downloaded the latest version of Sonarqube. Can explain how to integrate sonarqube and Android stdio.

Comment: Have you tried out the SonarQube Android Studio plugin?

Comment: https://medium.com/@sandeeptengale/integrate-sonarqube-for-android-application-development-8e40ec28e343

Comment: i downloaded sonarqube and run in http://localhost:9000/ and i added some dependencies to my android project. That's it i did.

Comment: @Ashvinsolanki In step 2, when i try to add sonar plugins(apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
apply plugin: 'jacoco-android'), gives some errors.

Comment: follow my solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811106/how-to-integrate-sonarqube-in-android-studio/54773428#54773428

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are steps to implement sonar in android

- Download more recent Sonar version. [http://www.sonarqube.org/downloads/][1]
- Unzip the archive.
- Go to sonarqube-7.x/bin (or whatever version you downloaded).
- Open a corresponding folder according to your operating system as (linux-x86- 
  64).
- Find sonar.sh (or StartSonar.bat for Windows).
- Open up a terminal window and execute: sonar.sh start (or just double click 
  StartSonar.bat on windows).
- This command will start sonar listening on localhost:9000.
- Open a browser and enter localhost:9000.The sonar web page should open.
- If you get “page not found” in your browser, try to refresh the page later.
- To add project in sonarqube server run ./gradlew sonar command on Android 
  Studio terminal.

Comment: It would we better if you post some gradle code as well, thanks for your efforts