# Finding duplicated code (Kotlin) in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, plugins, code-duplication

Is there a way to find duplicated (Copy/pasted code, repeated code) Kotlin code in Android Studio? 
I have Android Studio 4.0 but can't find this "Duplicated code fragment" option.

Are there any Android Studio plugins that do this job for Kotlin?

Comment: Seen this? https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/analyzing-duplicates.html

Comment: Thats for IntelliJ, I'm looking for Android Studio tools

Comment: You can also try to run SonarQube (https://www.sonarqube.org/) in Android studio (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43811106/how-to-integrate-sonarqube-in-android-studio)

Comment: @Harish Android Studio is based on Intellij

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can install the [sonarLint](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7973-sonarlint) plugin.

It has many rules which are executed on source code to find possible issues like bugs or code smells.

[image: example 1]

This is done with the rules provided by default.

Other example of repetition:

[image: example 2]

Just need to install the sonarLint plugin in Preferences/Plugins:

[image: sonarLint]

A more advanced tool you could check is [Gradle CPD plugin](https://github.com/aaschmid/gradle-cpd-plugin).
This is a Gradle plugin to find duplicate code using PMDs copy/paste detection (= CPD). You can find information about how to install it and how to use it in the same readme of the repository. CPD supports Kotlin since v6.10.0.

Comment: jeprubio, it seems to check the entire code between the two methods (the code should match exactly) and doesn't work when 1. The two methods differ even by a single line 2. There is duplicated code within the same method. Are there any other settings that we can tweak?

Comment: Well, if they are not identical (parameters or vars changed) it can also detect duplicates depending on the case, but it's not always perfect. In case you want it to have custom rules if you click on the SonarLint tab and then on the 'Configure Sonarlint' image (tools icon) you can set a SonarQube / SonarCloud configs on where to get custom rules. However, the ones by default are great and help a lot. In my opinion is the best tool